# setup rsync to delete files from my remote server once they have been successfully transfered to my local machine

Tags: server, ssh, backup, rsync

I need help setting up rsync to transfer files from my remote server to my local machine and then delete the files form the remote server once they have been moved successfully to the local machine.

I am currently using the following combination which does the job of copying from remote to local fine, but doesn't delete as I would like.

```
rsync -avvru --delete-excluded /remote/location /local/location
```

Each box has rsync installed, and the above command is being run from the remote server pushing to the local machine

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely familiar with all of the functions of `rsync` but I use it for backups. I would recommend  just making a `bash` script with the `rsync` and a find and delete script or just a `rm -r`.

Something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

rsync -avvru --delete-excluded /remote/location /local/location

rm -rf /remote/location
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

`rsync -avvu --remove-source-files /remote/source /local/destination`

While this deletes successfully transferred files from the source, it does not delete directories.

The `--delete-excluded` option enables deletion of excluded files from destination, not from the source. To simplify, all `--delete` options delete files from destination, which you probably don't want.

Also, there is no need for `-r` in this case. The `-a` parameter implies it.